# How can I make my slideshow buttons work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I am trying to create a slideshow that has "Next" and "Previous" buttons. I have already created the slideshow, but I am having trouble creating the interactive buttons. For some reason, the buttons do not transition to the corresponding slide on the slideshow when they are clicked. I think it may be a problem in my JavaScript. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    currdeg  = 0;

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){
  if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 70px 0;
  font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #ed1c24;
}
.b {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #0072bc;
}
.c {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #39b54a;
}
.d {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #f26522;
}
.e {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #630460;
} 
.f {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #8c6239;
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}
.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 104px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}
.next { right: 5em; }
.prev { left: 5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item a">A</div>
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
    <div class="item d">D</div>
    <div class="item e">E</div>
    <div class="item f">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, you didn't include jQuery with your snippet.  That's what "$ is not defined" means.

Comment: Is there anyway I can add or link jquery to a JavaScript file?

Comment: There should be a link on the left side.  Or, you can copy paste this.  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script>

Comment: When i copy the code with included jquery in a file the buttons seem to work. You can switch the slides with the buttons "previous" and "next" in both directions.

Comment: I tried adding <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script> to my HTML file. The error goes away but the buttons still don't work.

Comment: I just added it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.